# how to restore back data in template using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to build a template like gridview. My problem is when I edit the data '123qwe' to '123' but when i click 'cancel' button not to edit the data. the data not restore back to '123qwe'. 
I have a workaround to solve this, however, it is not work in my computer but in jsfiddle, I want to know the reason and help to solve in a knockout.js format. Thank you~~~

code to attention:

```
// Reset button
self.reset = function (index) { 
    self.nameLists([]);
    $.each(og_arr, function(i,item){
        self.nameLists.push(new nameFilter(item.name));
    });
    this.editTemplate("readOnlyTemplate");
};
```

[program in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myhk2009/ov9onc0j/15/)

Comment: A simple way to achieve this would be to set const variables upon initialization and reassign these values to your observables in the reset function.  Also, depending on the size of your dataset using push() on an observableArray repeatedly can lead to performance issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in notion of canceling an edit. You are editing an observable. Have a look at [protected observables](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html), a simple extension that allows you to commit or reset a change.

Comment: thank for all of you to help, but can i use use custom binding / extends observable with subscribe to do that? i was able to get old value but i cannot how to integrate that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For general "undo" functionality, check out the [Memento](https://github.com/MrFrankel/Knockout-Memento) plugin for Knockout.

(I didn't write it, just a satisfied user)